# Add data validation to specific range (only the input message and title)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a specific range where I want to add a "info" window (a message into a yellow rectangle when you set your selection into that range, I thought the data validation method was the only one that could do that ?)

```
Debug.Print rTextInfoRange.Address
    With rTextInfoRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = sTitle
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = sSummaryText
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

*(most lines are probably useless, they were copied from the recording macro thing)*

Debug is:`$U$59:$Y$59` which is the range I want.

Nothing happens. With nothing I mean there's no data validation set (and thus no message). But I have no error neither.

Somebody can help please ? Thank.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` prior to this? Are  you sure you're looking at the correct (parent) sheet for `rTextInfoRange`?

Comment: @BigBen I have one error line somewhere in my project, I put it into comments and still nothing (neither an error). This is the range line:
`Set rTextInfoRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetToStore).Range(sPRODUCTGROUP & rowToStore & ":" & Chr(Asc(sDISPLACEMENTROW) + 1) & rowToStore)` looks correct.

Comment: Tried this one in a new document, and works like a charm :(

Comment: Ok found it, but too shameful to type it here :p see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, my "sSummaryText" wasn't declared and it seems like if your message isn't completed you don't see anything.

Comment: Instead of typing an answer, you could just delete your question :-)

Comment: I've voted to close as a typo.